# Bleak client: problem with sending bytes to BLE device (E104-BT02)

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm trying to send bytes using Python and Bleak (https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module from PC (Windows) to Ebyte BLE module E104-BT02.

The code is following:

```py
ADDRESS = "ED:F5:E8:F6:DE:D8"
MODEL_NBR_UUID = "00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
UART_TX_CHAR_UID = "0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
UART_RX_CHAR_UUID = "0000fff2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
def handle_rx(_: int, data: bytearray):
    print("received:", data)

async def main(ble_address):
    device = await BleakScanner.find_device_by_address(ble_address, timeout=60.0)
    if not device:
        raise BleakError(f"A device with address {ble_address} could not be found.")
    async with BleakClient(ble_address) as client:
        await client.start_notify(UART_TX_CHAR_UID, handle_rx)
        print("Connected, start typing and press ENTER...")
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        while True:
            data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, sys.stdin.buffer.readline)
            if data == b'\r\n':
                break         
            await client.write_gatt_char(UART_RX_CHAR_UUID, data)
            print("sent:", data)
            print(res)
    
asyncio.run(main(ADDRESS))
```

`await client.write_gatt_char(UART_RX_CHAR_UUID, data)` should send every byte that I enter through the console. But I get nothing on my module.

However, if I use BLEConsole (https://sensboston.github.io/BLEConsole/) or a mobile App. LightBlue everything is OK, I get bytes without any problems. Characteristic UUID `0000fff2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` is correct. I feel that it is some stupid thing, but I've been trying to find something for 3 days. I would be very grateful for any ideas

P. S. Everything works perfectly in the opposite direction. When I send bytes from the E104-BT02 module, the PC gets and shows them in the console. (characteristic UUID 0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)

Comment: You example looks very close to the one in the repo https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/master/examples/uart_service.py. Could it be that the line endings are the issue?

Comment: Yes, I used this code to see that it works. I thought that it is something due to the line ending, but I tried different options. Now the results of sending line look like this: "Connected, start typing and press ENTER... 12345 sent: b'12345\r\n' "also, I tried line ending just b'\n' and without any special symbols... It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I'm going to try this code using Linux. Could you please, write one more time about how I can get additional data using 2 opened terminals?

Comment: The information you are looking for is in my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7721752/ukbaz?tab=profile)